# Training on promise and await / async with fetch in another function

Tags: node.js, promise, async-await, fetch

I go on with praticing in JS.

This time, I try to do quite the same thing using async / await or promise :

```
const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1';
```

1. Async / await version :

```
async function getData() {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.json();
    return data;
}

const callGetData = async () => {
    try {
        const data = await getData()
        console.log(data);        
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("Something gone wrong")        
    }
}
```

2. Promise version

```
function getData() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fetch(url)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => resolve(data))
        .catch(error => reject(error));
    });
}

const callGetData = () => {
    getData()
    .then(data => console.log(data))
    .catch(error => console.log("Something gone wrong"));
}
```

and finally :

```
callGetData();
```

Both snippets seem to work. It's easier to me to write the async / await version.

Questions :

- do I use promise properly in this case ?
- is there some possible improvements ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fectch` is also a **promise** and you are trying to wrap a promise inside a new `Promise`

more on the **Promise version** you can simply return it from the function as

```js
getData(url){
 return fetch(url)
 .then(response => response.json()).then(jsonResponse=>jsonResponse)
 .catch(err=>err)
}
```

now `getData` returns a **promise**. we can simply do as :

```js
getData().then(data=>console.log(data))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Obvious with this. I knew I was somewhere wrong.